# How to find largest sequence of numbers in a line?

Tags: java

I have a class assignment where we have to use Math.random to generate values of 0 or 1 representing heads and tails respectively. The point of the program is to have the user input the number of times the coin is flipped, and the program then spits out a string of random 0s and 1s representing the flips. The program then has to find and state the longest number of heads in a row.

eg.
(heads = 0 / tails = 1)
number of tosses: 10
result: 0001100100
longest sequence of heads: 3

this is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class CoinFlip
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int Toss;                   // State variable for tosses
    int Heads;                  // State variable for # of heads

    System.out.println("Enter number of tosses:");
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Toss = input1.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < Toss ; i++)
    {
      int Coin = (int) (Math.random() + .5);
      System.out.print(Coin);                               // Prints sequence of flips
    } 

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Longest sequence of heads is ");    // Says largest sequence of heads
  }
}
```

I'm stuck as to how I read the sequence and then display the longest consecutive head count.

Comment: Hint: do not read the sequence back, instead add the processing to the loop that generates the sequence.

Comment: The problem is that you are just printing out `coin` values without keeping the track of the sequence. So first you need a new String variable that will  hold the `sequence`. Then you will need another loop to determine the longest  consecutive head count of your sequence variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Just count zeros and reset counter when not zero.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.print("Enter number of tosses: ");
    int[] arr = new int[new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println("Longest sequence of heads is " + findLongestZeroSequence(arr));
}

public static int findLongestZeroSequence(int... arr) {
    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 0, cur = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            res = Math.max(res, ++cur);
        else
            cur = 0;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to do this. I take the String that you were printing and made a `String` out of it. I pass this string as a parameter to the function and count the consecutive 0 in it.

This is the code for the same:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int Toss;                   // State variable for tosses

        System.out.println("Enter number of tosses:");
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Toss = input1.nextInt();
        StringBuffer coinSequenceBuffer = new StringBuffer(Toss);

        for (int i = 0; i < Toss; i++) {
            int Coin = (int) (Math.random() + .5);
            System.out.print(Coin);                               // Prints sequence of flips
            coinSequenceBuffer.append(Coin);
        }
        String coinSequence = coinSequenceBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println("");
        int numberOfConsecutiveHead = findNumberOfConsecutiveHead(coinSequence);
        System.out.println("Longest sequence of heads is " + numberOfConsecutiveHead);
    }

    private static int findNumberOfConsecutiveHead(String coinSequence) {
        int count = 1;
        int max = 0;
        // Starting loop from 1 since we want to compare it with the char at index 0
        for (int i = 1; i < coinSequence.length(); i++) {
            if (coinSequence.charAt(i) == '1') {
                // Since we are not intersted in counting 1's as per the question
                continue;
            }
            if (coinSequence.charAt(i) == coinSequence.charAt(i - 1)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count > max) {  // Record current run length, is it the maximum?
                    max = count;
                }
                count = 1; // Reset the count
            }
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding comments so that you can easily understand it. Let me know if you face any issue in understanding it.

Comment: `StringBuffer coinSequenceBuffer = new StringBuffer(Toss);` -> `StringBuilder` should be used!

Comment: Yeah, Agree. It could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at it:

```
class CoinFlip {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Get number of tosses from user
        System.out.print("Enter number of tosses: ");
        System.out.flush();
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int toss = input1.nextInt();
    
        // Build a string of random '0's and '1's of the specified length (number of tosses)
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < toss ; i++)
        {
            long coin = Math.round(Math.random());
            sb.append(coin == 0? '0' : '1');
        }
        String seq = sb.toString();
    
        // Print the generated String
        System.out.println(seq);
    
        // Walk through the string tallying up runs of heads
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < seq.length() ; i++) {
            if (seq.charAt(i) == '0') {
                count += 1;
            } else {
                if (count > max)
                    max = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        // Gotta check at the end to see if the longest sequence of heads
        // was at the end of the string
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
    
        // Print the length of the longest sequence
        System.out.println("Longest sequence of heads is " + max);
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter number of tosses: 40
1000001000000010010101011000011100001000
Longest sequence of heads is 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip {
    private static final int  HEADS = 0;
    private static final int  TAILS = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of tosses: ");
        int toss = input1.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int longest = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(toss);
        for (int i = 0; i < toss; i++) {
            int coin = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) % 2);
            sb.append(coin);
            System.out.printf("Got %d [%s]%n", coin, (coin == HEADS ? "HEADS" : "TAILS"));
            if (coin == HEADS) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("count = " + count);
            }
            else {
                if (count > longest) {
                    longest = count;
                    System.out.println("longest = " + longest);
                }
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (count > longest) {
            longest = count;
            System.out.println("longest = " + longest);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.print("Longest sequence of heads is " + longest);
    }
}
```

In order to generate a random number which must be either 0 (zero) or 1 (one), I call method [random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) of class `java.lang.Math`. The method returns a `double` between 0.0 and 1.0. Multiplying by ten and then performing modulo 2 operation on that number returns either 0.0 or 1.0 which is a `double` and therefore needs to be cast to an `int`.

Each time the above calculation returns 0 (zero) I increment a count. If the calculation returns 1 (one) then I check whether the count is greater than `longest` and update `longest` accordingly, after which I reset the count back to zero.

Note that if the last toss is "heads" then the check for the longest sequence will not be performed. Hence I repeat the check for the longest sequence after the `for` loop.

At the end of the `for` loop, I have all the required information, i.e. the string that records all the results of all the coin tosses plus the longest sequence of heads.

Here is sample output:

```
Enter number of tosses: 10
Got 1 [TAILS]
Got 1 [TAILS]
Got 1 [TAILS]
Got 0 [HEADS]
count = 1
Got 1 [TAILS]
longest = 1
Got 0 [HEADS]
count = 1
Got 0 [HEADS]
count = 2
Got 1 [TAILS]
longest = 2
Got 0 [HEADS]
count = 1
Got 0 [HEADS]
count = 2
1110100100
Longest sequence of heads is 2
```